# Aside from visiting Casinos in LAS, what else is there to do?

Tags: las-vegas, casinos

Aside from visiting Casinos in LAS, what else is there to do? We are going to visit with our staff and are looking for events besides the day to day casino operations.

Comment: Welcome to TSE. One of the expectations of Stack Exchange is that you demonstrate your initial efforts at research.  There any number of websites about shopping, museums and galleries, adventure excursions, and so forth in and around Las Vegas. As it stands, this question is too broad to be well-answered in our format. I strongly encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help] for additional guidance.

Comment: How many are you, what's the age range/average, what's your budget, when are you going, how long?

Comment: I assume LAS here refers to the whole city of Las Vegas, and not just the airport?

Comment: you might be interested in https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/19875/one-afternoon-night-in-vegas-what-to-do/19876#19876 and https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/18147/what-to-do-in-las-vegas-without-having-to-sin/18160#18160 - we have a whole https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/las-vegas you can also explore

Answer (score 3):

You  can go to see the Grand Canyon by helicopter.  The expensive way is a direct flight from McCarran, which also gives you an aerial view of Vegas and the Hoover Dam.  This takes a few hours.  The cheaper option involves a bus much of the way and takes essentially all day.

We did the former a few years ago. The helicopter ride and its views were better than the actual stop in the canyon.

Answer (score 2):

- Rides such as those over Stratosphere or the roller coaster over New York, New York
- Shows such as Cirque du Soleil, stand up comedy, magic show etc
- Shoot machine guns or even AK-47
- Go off roading in the desert https://www.trailsoffroad.com/states/NV
- Red Rock Canyon https://www.redrockcanyonlv.org/
- National Parks e.g Grand Canyon, Zion, Bryce Canyon etc
- this is stretching it but if you have a few days, I might suggest driving to Horseshoe Bend, Antelope Canyon, Arches National Park, Canyonlands, Sedona etc.

Answer (score 1):

In the summer, most hotels have incredible pool areas. Some hotels have pool parties.

All year long:

- Just strolling along the strip to see all these casinos (both from the inside and the outside) and their animations (Treasure Island pirate ship, Mirage volcano, Bellagio Fountains, Venetian Canal and Gondolas...) is quite entertaining
- Circus Circus has an indoor amusement park with rides and everything
- The Mirage has dolphins, lions, and more.
- Lots of shopping
- There are tons of very nice restaurants
- Lots of bars
- Lots of nightclubs
- You can also play golf
- And of course you have all the shows, including aerobatics (Cirque du Soleil etc.), magic, concerts, fights, and so on.

And it goes on and on.

If you have the money, you can stay there for 2 weeks during the summer and not get bored without even gambling.